Keyboard and mouse unresponsive on KVM switch
I have a KVM switch between my Ubuntu (22.04) and Windows to share my monitor, keyboard and mouse.
90% of the time it works. However, 10% of the time when I switch back to Ubuntu my keyboard and mouse are unresponsive and I have to hit the shutdown button on the PC. I think it's always acted like this.
Assuming it's software related:
I'm looking at /var/log/syslog and there's a lot of events logged.
What events can I post here, to help diagnose if this can be fixed?
KVM brand is Sgeyr, 2x1 (2 machines, 1 display).
